# Azure WsFederation token in web farm scenario

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, ws-federation

I'm trying to follow an Azure sample to integrate Azure AD into my MVC 4.6 web app via WSFederation provided here https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation

This sample uses cookies to store authentication token. I want to know if this solution works in webfarm or load-balanced scenarios? Or do I need to implement it differently?

Thanks for your guidance and pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This sample uses cookies to store authentication token. I want to know if this solution works in webfarm or load-balanced scenarios?

If it uses cookies to store authentication token, and the servers on the farm share the machine key used to encrypt and decrypt cookie, the example should work in webfarm or load-balanced scenarios.

Comment: I added following under system.web section of web.config <machineKey 
      validationKey="105E14408F7F5794AA7CB29017D753AFD7EBB58B6040A8CC73D5E66C024DFC2BD2D1A52A62F2AF6696319AE3BDC551FFB070B650D418CAF2BF8FFDF46CA791E7"
      decryptionKey="C7631DEAE361FB4C792D2D10FC1B2BFCAAB15CCDF6B65D5F8370845E650BE1E2"
      validation="SHA1"
      decryption="AES" />. Is it right thing to do and handle the webfarm scenario?

Comment: please refer to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855666/adding-machinekey-to-web-config-on-web-farm-sites) that could be helpful.