# Is there a best way to protect or encrypt the ids of entities in WebAPI?

Tags: c#, encryption, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I use asp.net WebAPI to provide the service.But I found to explore the id of the entity(Resources identity ) is not a good idea.

eg. if you pass your UserProfile ID to get user's  profile. because the id is auto incremented in DB, if someone iterates the Ids to get the others' profile, it will make the users' profiles to leak.(maybe you suggest to use GUID, But int type id has better performance)

So I want to encrypt the IDs with time in WebAPI filters. Is there a good demo for this?

Update: don't confused by User demo. If you have products. first you get the products list,then you will get product detail by product id . How to proect product id.

Comment: Why do you want this? Doesn't your API have an authentication mechanism?

Comment: you can use OAuth Jwt authentication

Comment: I allow client to access the ids  by Anonymous not special users @john

Comment: What do you hope to achieve by using an encrypted id? I mean, it clearly isn't to restrict access to the resource. Unless you are hoping for security by obscurity, which is a bad route to go down anyway - security by obscurity isn't security.

Comment: @john I don't want to avoid someone to iterate the Ids.(not use GUID directly)

Comment: If you want to encrypt the ids, you could use the MachineKey class.

Comment: does it support load balances ?

Comment: @john The MachineKey is used to encrypt and secure the page’s ViewState. By default, the .NET framework uses that machine’s own MachineKey, but should your view state get sent to another content delivery server with a different key, well, then the ViewState will be invalid. That’s something of a problem.

Comment: You can share a key between machines, so that the encryption result will be the same on multiple machines. It's used for encrypting access tokens in asp.net :) See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855666/adding-machinekey-to-web-config-on-web-farm-sites), specifically [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx#paght000007_webfarmdeploymentconsiderations).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147888/discussion-between-huoxudong125-and-john).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't hide the id's but you can control it with roles. Return resource with different amount of properties based on who's requesting.

If it's anonymous call, maybe don't return anything or return only data which is public and can be seen by anyone any way.

If it's logged in user, maybe he can see more data about other users.

If it's admin who is requesting that information, he can see even more data.

If the user is requesting information about himself, even more data.

Now maybe it would be better to have different endpoints for different level of access so that it's easier to define and document your api, for example for user to get his own information, it would be /user/me.