# How to host Asp.net application in docker swarm mode load balancer

Tags: asp.net, docker, iis, cluster-computing, swarm

I have asp.net application now that application is running under VM host iis.  i am planing to deploy using docker swarm. But i am facing machinekey issue. how i can run this application using docker swarm mode. We will scale dynamically in and out.  Machine key is always contact same machine. if we are hosting application in cluster mode we have to add macinekey in web.config file.  Is there any solution for this.

Comment: See if this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855666/adding-machinekey-to-web-config-on-web-farm-sites

Answer (score 0):

i have put the machine key in my web.config file and it works fine. but some Hyper links are not working properly. i need to fix.

```
<machineKey validationKey="C50B3C89CB21F4F1422FF158A5B42D0E8DB8CB5CDA1742572A487D9401E3400267682B202B746511891C1BAF47F8D25C07F6C39A104696DB51F17C529AD3CABE" decryptionKey="8A9BE8FD67AF6979E7D20198CFEA50DD3D3799C77AF2B72F" validation="SHA1" />
```