# error The antiforgery token could not be decrypted. The key {guid} was not found in the key ring

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

We're running an ASP.NET MVC Core 1.1 application on a web farm with 2 servers and ran into these exceptions, when a user is attempting to upload a file. We believe this is happening because the get request is from one server and their post may be going to the other web server, leading to the keys being not matched?

Is there a way to get around this issue?

Error 1:
The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.

> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String
>   serializedToken) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery.DeserializeTokens(HttpContext
>   httpContext, AntiforgeryTokenSet antiforgeryTokenSet,
>   AntiforgeryToken& cookieToken, AntiforgeryToken& requestToken) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery.ValidateTokens(HttpContext
>   httpContext, AntiforgeryTokenSet antiforgeryTokenSet) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery.d__9.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter.d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__20.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.HttpMethodOverrideMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exce

Error 2: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.

> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String
>   serializedToken) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery.DeserializeTokens(HttpContext
>   httpContext, AntiforgeryTokenSet antiforgeryTokenSet,
>   AntiforgeryToken& cookieToken, AntiforgeryToken& requestToken) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery.ValidateTokens(HttpContext
>   httpContext, AntiforgeryTokenSet antiforgeryTokenSet) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery.d__9.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter.d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__20.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.HttpMethodOverrideMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a machine key defined (see this: [Adding machineKey to web.config on web-farm sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855666/adding-machinekey-to-web-config-on-web-farm-sites))?  Both servers should have the same [machineKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx#paght000007_webfarmdeploymentconsiderations) config entry (can be generated within IIS or via online tools).

```
<machineKey  
  validationKey="GENERATED VALUE"           
  decryptionKey="GENERATED VALUE"
  validation="SHA1"
  decryption="AES" />
```

Answer (score 1):

For DotNetCore Apps running on IIS, if your application pool is set to use AppPoolIdentity, then you need to make sure "Load User Profile" is set to "True" in the Application Pool Advanced Settings.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/default-settings?view=aspnetcore-2.1

> 2. If the user profile is available, keys are persisted to the %LOCALAPPDATA%\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys folder. If the operating
>      system is Windows, the keys are encrypted at rest using DPAPI.

Comment: I deployed the app to a windows shared hosting and got the same error, can you recommend for fixing the error in this case?