# Razor Pages - HTTP Error 400 (Invalid Anti Forgery Token) when idle the web site

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, blazor-server-side, antiforgerytoken

I'm developing a web site in Blazor Server Side. My Login page is a Razor Page and everything works as expected, but if a user leaves their browser open for a period of time around 20 minutes and then performs the login they get an Http Error 400. I think it is for the Anti Forgery Token, because if you delete the cookie ".AspNetCore.Antiforgery" you got the same error. What should I do to solve this issue? What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application is being hosted in IIS I recommend setting `Load User Profile = True` in the application's app pool > Advanced settings menu. I had a similar issue in the past and I noticed every time the application restarted in IIS the keys were not persisted and any form opened before the restart is useless. However as soon as I changed the setting the key persisted. https://codeshorts.com/ASP-NET-Core-IIS-Invalid-Anti-Forgery-Token-Error-400

This also seems to have been an issue with Azure hosted apps
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52302702/1843966

Comment: I have tested this solution and it worked very well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to apply [`IgnoreAntiforgeryToken` Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.ignoreantiforgerytokenattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to `LoginModel` class to skip antiforgery token validation, like below.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    //...
```

Note: normally, disabling antiforgery token validation is not recommended. But in this thread, applying it to LoginModel (user login functionality) should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found this approach using code so you can catch the exception if it does fail

[image]